# How to set interval time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer, setinterval

I have use following function for timer

```
 function startTimer(duration) {
        $rootScope.timer = duration;
        $rootScope.minute = 0;
        $rootScope.second = 0;
        $rootScope.Minutes = 0;
        $rootScope.Seconds = 0;
        setInterval(function () {
            $rootScope.minute = parseInt($rootScope.timer / 60, 10)
            $rootScope.second = parseInt($rootScope.timer % 60, 10);
            $rootScope.Minutes = $rootScope.minute < 10 ? "0" + 
            $rootScope.minute : $rootScope.minute;
            $rootScope.Seconds = $rootScope.second < 10 ? "0" + 
            $rootScope.second : $rootScope.second;
            if (--$rootScope.timer < 0) {
                $rootScope.timer = duration;
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

startTimer(300);
```

I am using `$rootScope.Minutes` and `$rootScope.Seconds` in view to display time. And time reduce by seconds . but if i close timer and open again it will reduce by 2 seconds. and again i close and open then it will reduce by 3 seconds. like wise iterations goes. I do not know where i did mistake. Please help me.

Comment: post full code in fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `startTimer`, it will fire off another `setInterval`, which will run independently. Because you are using the same variables, each `setInterval` will operate on your `$rootScope.timer` variable independently.

The solution is to save a handle to the `setInterval` at the start, and `clearInterval` before setting a new interval.

```
function startTimer(duration) {
        $rootScope.timer = duration;
        $rootScope.minute = 0;
        $rootScope.second = 0;
        $rootScope.Minutes = 0;
        $rootScope.Seconds = 0;

        // modified bit
        if($rootScope.internvalhandle) clearInterval($rootScope.internvalhandle);

        $rootScope.internvalhandle = setInterval(function () {
            $rootScope.minute = parseInt($rootScope.timer / 60, 10)
            $rootScope.second = parseInt($rootScope.timer % 60, 10);
            $rootScope.Minutes = $rootScope.minute < 10 ? "0" + 
            $rootScope.minute : $rootScope.minute;
            $rootScope.Seconds = $rootScope.second < 10 ? "0" + 
            $rootScope.second : $rootScope.second;
            if (--$rootScope.timer < 0) {
                $rootScope.timer = duration;
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

startTimer(300);
```